# Visual Studio - Hide SPELL type messages In Error List

Tags: visual-studio

How do I suppress the spelling mistake information messages in the error list?
I do not want to switch spell checker off but I don't want them filling up the messages section of the Error List.
[image]

All google results say to switch off spell checker.

Edit: the previous spellchecker used to just highlight errors in line and not show them in the error list.

Comment: you could uncheck the messages button.

Comment: What would be the point of having the spell checker enabled if you could not see the errors that it detected?

Comment: Are you really *Upsert* about this?  ;-)   If these are user-facing messages then fixing the errors seems like a good thing.